# Cree XHP70 LED Drivers at 6v / 12v

Tags: led, led-driver

I have some questions regarding Cree XHP 70 LED Drivers.

I have 2 LED drivers Cree Model XHP70 from kaidomain. I want to run a LED at 12v.

**xhp 70 spec**

Maximum Drive Current: 4.8 A (6 V) / 2.4 A (12 V)
Typical Forward Voltage 5.8 V @ 2100 mA (6 V) / 11.6 V @ 1050 mA (12 V)

***Cree First Driver Specs ([ref.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180622011340/http://www.kaidomain.com/p/S024010.4-18V-3-Mode-Drive-Circuit-Board-for-1-x-Cree-XHP70))***

Operating voltage: 4-18V, maximum 20V
LED current: 4.5-5A

***Cree Second Driver Specs*** ([ref.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170701035805/http://www.kaidomain.com/p/S024447.6V-12V-5-Mode-Driver-Circuit-Board-for-1-x-Cree-XHP70))

Operating voltage: 4-12V
LED current: 3A

I was thinking using a 4S3P of 18650 (3200 mA) battery that could give: 14.4v, 9600 mAh. Not sure but theses drivers seem to be Constant current drivers. So the first one could be used in 6v mode but current seem any way too high.

The second could be used in 12v mode but the current seem also high.

I would like to have your confirmation about running these drivers at 12v.

Comment: You've linked the same driver (3A version) twice.

Comment: We don't expect every post to be perfect, but posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get read and upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your post to improve it. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: i updated links

Comment: improve spelling etc...